# Creating my own \tableofcontents in plain TeX

Tags: table-of-contents, plain-tex, auxiliary-files, write-file

I'd like to define my own table of contents in TeX (not LaTeX, so without packages) to have a fine control on what goes there, how the numbers are displayed, etc. Basically what I would like is to write a file that looks like

```
1.0.0.Title of chapter 1
1.1.0.Title of section 1
1.1.1.Title of subsection 1.1
1.1.2.Title of subsection 1.2
2.0.0.Title of chapter 2
A.0.0.Title of appendix A
```

and read it with these kind of options:

- write a table of contents including only the chapters
- write a table of contents including only the chapter 1 and its sections
- ...

To do so I have 2 questions:

1. How can I (re)write some content at a particular line to keep my file sorted? (e.g. if after a second compilation I change the title of chapter 2 and I add a subsection 1.3 in chapter 1, how do I update my file?)
2. How do `\read` this file? I'm new with file writing/reading in TeX so I don't know if there is any care to take or a special way to do this?

---

After thinking of my question, question 2 might trivial if the file is written in the template

```
\toccontent{1}{0}{0}{Title of chapter 1}
...
```

so that it only has to be `\input`ted, after redefining `\toccontent` according to what and how I want to display (e.g. "do nothing if the 2nd argument is not 0").

Comment: I don't understand very well what you mean with your second question. Could you give an example?

Comment: @Bernard my question is: once the file is written, how do I `\read` it back in TeX? I never used file writing/reading in TeX so I don't know how it works or if there is any care to take of something. (I updated the question)

Comment: @Ivaneesbeeck: I still can't grasp what you try  to obtain exactly

Comment: LaTeX makes the table of contents with help of an auxiliary .toc file – that's why when you change the title of a chapter,  say, seeing the modification in the final pdf requires2 compilations. Could you give a minimal concrete example of what you want to do?

Comment: @Bernard I thought I gave a minimal example in my post: write a file with all those chapters/sections/subsections titles and from this file 1, extract a table of chapters; 2, extract a table of contents restricted to chapter 1 and its sections. (I forgot to mention, but of course I'm aware that this will need 2 compilations as LaTeX' normal `\tableofcontents`)

Comment: @Ivaneesbeek: OK your updated formulation is clearer. Cmhughes's answer gives the full details of what I sketched in my answer. In short: you have nothing special to do but compile.

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, I suggest you to use `eplain` that already has all the needed tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `eplain` macros you can write to the `.toc` file and read the result in.  Commands such as `\writenumberedtocentry` produce lines in the toc file prefaced by e.g. `\tocchapterentry`.
You thus need to define commands the `\tocchapterentry`, `\tocsectionentry` for formatting/processing the material read in.

Here is a very basic example of a document with two versions of the table of contents, for the same toc file, the second only containing the chapters.

[image: Sample output]

```
\input eplain

\newif\ifchaponlytoc
\chaponlytocfalse

\def\tocchapterentry#1#2#3{{\bf #2 #1 page #3}\par}
\def\tocsectionentry#1#2#3{\ifchaponlytoc\else#2 #1 page #3\par\fi}

\newcount\chapno
\newcount\secno
\newcount\subsecno

\chapno=0\secno=0\subsecno=0

{\bf Table of Contents}
\smallskip

\readtocfile

\bigskip

{\bf Table of Chapters}
\smallskip

\chaponlytoctrue
\readtocfile

\bigskip

\advance\chapno by 1\secno=0\subsecno=0
\xdef\fullchapno{\the\chapno .\the\secno .\the\subsecno}
{\bf \the\chapno\ First Chapter}
\writenumberedtocentry{chapter}{First Chapter}{\fullchapno}

Text of first chapter.

\medskip
\advance\secno by 1\subsecno=0
\xdef\fullchapno{\the\chapno .\the\secno .\the\subsecno}
{\it \the\chapno.\the\secno\ First Section}
\writenumberedtocentry{section}{First Section}{\fullchapno}

Text of first section.

\bigskip

\advance\chapno by 1\secno=0\subsecno=0
\xdef\fullchapno{\the\chapno .\the\secno .\the\subsecno}
{\bf \the\chapno\ Second Chapter}
\writenumberedtocentry{chapter}{Second Chapter}{\fullchapno}

Text of second chapter.

\bye
```

In the body of the document, each chapter, section etc. updates its counters, defines `\fullchapno` and writes the infomation out to the toc file.  Note that for `\writenumberedtocentry` the last argument only gets its first term exanded, so `\fullchapno` needs to contain the expanded chapter number.

Now at the top of the document we introduce a toggle via `\ifchaponlytoc` to determine whether we want to only have chapters in the toc or all levels.  The lower level toc print commands then test this toggle before deciding whether to output anything.  An alternative way to proceed would be to simply define these commands differently before the second reading of the toc file.

Of course much of the code above can be packaged in to macros, but also many of the details will depend on how you set up your sectioning commands and add entries to the toc.  I hope this gives you a starting idea.  Look at the [`eplain` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eplain) for much more information.

Comment: A side-issue: `\newif\ifchaponlytoc` already starts with `\chaponlytocfalse`, so we do not have to add `\chaponlytocfalse`, do we?

Comment: @awllower Yes, that it is correct, new conditions created by `\newif` are initially false.  But I find it useful to have an explicit initial setting, for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

The [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc) package offers what you need, and in particular, its command `printcontents` command can be used.

The `printcontents` command has syntax

```
\printcontents[name]{prefix}{start-level}{toc-code}
```

which I have used in two ways in the code below:

```
\startcontents[chapters]
...
...
% prints only chapters
\printcontents[chapters]{}{0}{
% locally set the tocdepth for *this* printing of the toc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
}
```

which will print out only your *chapter* files because I have set the `tocdepth` to `0` locally.

I have also used

```
\startcontents[zebras]
\chapter{zebras}
% prints this chapter and its sections
\printcontents[zebras]{}{0}{
% locally set the tocdepth for *this* printing of the toc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
}
\section{}
\lipsum
\section{}
\section{}
\stopcontents[zebras]
```

to print you a `minitoc` just for that `chapter`. You can increase the `tocdepth` locally if you wish to include other heading levels in this partial `toc`.

Here's a complete MWE that demonstrates the idea- for future reading, please consult the documentation; you may also be interested in the [`minitoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/minitoc) package which offers some similar functionality.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titletoc}   % customize tableofcontents
\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text

% the printcontents command is from the titletoc package
% and it has the form
%
% \printcontents[name]{prefix}{start-level}{toc-code}
\begin{document}

% start partial toc for the chapters
\startcontents[chapters]

% start partial toc for this chapter- call it zebras, for example
\startcontents[zebras]
\chapter{zebras}
% prints this chapter and its sections- adjust the tocdepth
% to get deeper headings such as subsection, etc
\printcontents[zebras]{}{0}{
    % locally set the tocdepth for *this* printing of the toc
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
}
\section{}
\lipsum
\section{}
\section{}
\stopcontents[zebras]

% new chapter
\chapter{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\lipsum

% prints only chapters by setting the tocdepth locally
\printcontents[chapters]{}{0}{
    % locally set the tocdepth for *this* printing of the toc
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry! you posted while I was writing and checking my answer.

Comment: I clarified my question: I'm looking for a solution in "pure" TeX, not LaTeX. However thanks for your answer, it may be useful for a LaTeX user :-)

Comment: dear down voter: please let me know why you down voted my answer- I'd love to improve my answer

Comment: I down voted it for the main reason that it's not a package-free solution and it doesn't answer any of my two questions. This is not the kind of answer I was looking for (I rewrote my question which may be clearer now).

Comment: You are, of course, free to use your votes as you please, but generally speaking on this site we use down votes very sparingly. Your question does *not* contain a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), nor was it obvious that you only wanted a `plain-tex` solution- you might consider modifying your tags

Comment: I don't get where I didn't provide a MWE. I gave an example of file that I'd like to write and an example of how I want to use this file. It wasn't a TeX example for the main reason that I don't know how to do this it TeX, which is the main point of my question. I downvoted your answer for the main reason that it is currently the most popular one although it doesn't provide the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you only have to compile twice: once to modify the .toc file, the second time to incorporate it to the pdf or dvi.

To write a table of contents including only the chapters, write:

```
\setcounter{\tocnumdepth}{0} \tableofcontents
```

The titletoc package (included in titlesec, but can be used alone) lets you customise the table of contents, and allows partial table of contents (/figures/tables) with specific commands:

```
\startcontents, \stopcontents, \resumecontents and \printcontents
```

Details are in the titlesec documentation, § 6.3 to 6.5

Comment: Well, ignoring the fact that the question got changed after you posted this, still, the other answer contains more information than this one, and it was posted before this.

Comment: The question is not about doing it in LaTeX.

Comment: It was not quite clear from the first formulation…